# numpy inplace mixed operand type operations possible?

Tags: python, numpy

In C/C++, I can do:

```
uint8 i = 10;
i = uint8(i * 1.1f);
```

In numpy:

```
i = array([10,], dtype=np.uint8);
i.mutiply(i, 1.1, out=i);
```

... fails because the result of the operands (int*float) is not the same dtype as out.

Nevertheless, this is what I'd like to do - in-place mixed type operations in order to avoid unnecessarily created very many, and very large matrices.

Is there any support for this in numpy?

Comment: The dtype determines how the output will be stored in memory. You can't simply replace each `uint8` value with a `float` without rebuilding the entire array, so there's no real sense trying to do this in-place.

Comment: "there's no real sense trying" - respectfully, I disagree.
With large data, it saves both and time, cpu, and therefore cuts money and complexity at scale.

numpy *could* provide such operations (just as c/c++ provides in-place operations for basic types).
My question is if it does, or am I forced to (unnecessarily) duplicate the array, cast is, and assign it back to the original.

Comment: You're assuming you can losslessly cast a 64-bit `float` value into a 8-bit unsigned integer. That seems unlikely.

Comment: No, I am not. Rounding down to integers is fine with me, and common in many application (e.g. machine vision, deep learning at scale).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.multiply`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) with `casting='unsafe'`:

```
In [8]: i = array([10,], dtype=np.uint8)

In [9]: i
Out[9]: array([10], dtype=uint8)

In [10]: np.multiply(i, 1.1, out=i, casting='unsafe')
Out[10]: array([11], dtype=uint8)

In [11]: i
Out[11]: array([11], dtype=uint8)
```